# Narrowing Down a Date Range for CalendarDiagnosticObjects

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a script where I am trying to determine what users on a list of VIPs have reservations against a list of conference rooms so service desk can provision the room beforehand. I want to only pull data for the next 7 days, but the script seems to be pulling all the data... Old and new. I have been having a devil of a time taming this thing... Here is the code:

```
$NetPath = "PathToShare"
$VIPs = gc ("$NetPath"+"VIPs.txt")
$Rooms = gc ("$NetPath"+"Rooms.txt")
$StartDate = Get-Date
$EndDate = $StartDate.AddDays(7)
$DateRange = $StartDate.ToString("yyMMdd") + "-" + 
$EndDate.ToString("yyMMdd")
$ExportPath = "$NetPath\Output\VIPReservations_$DateRange.csv"

$Info = ForEach ($VIP in $VIPs) {
$Meetings = Get-CalendarDiagnosticObjects -Identity $VIP | Where-Object {$_.location -match ($Rooms -join '|')}

Foreach ($Meeting in $Meetings) {
    $Data = $Meeting | Where-Object { $_.StartTime -ge $StartDate -and $_.StartTime -lt $EndDate } | Select-Object location, starttime

    if ($Data -ne $null) {
        $hash = @{
            VIP = $VIP
            Location = $Data.location
            StartTime = $Data.StartTime
        }
        $Return = New-Object psobject -Property $hash
        $Return
    }
}
}

$UniqueInfo = $Info | Select-Object * -Unique | Where-Object { $_.Location -ne $null -and 
$_.StartTime -ne $null }
$UniqueInfo | Export-Csv $ExportPath -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

Any assistance would be appreciated, this is kicking my butt and it should be simple. Obviously, the troublesome line is:

```
$Data = $Meeting | Where-Object { $_.StartTime -ge $StartDate -and $_.StartTime -lt $EndDate } | Select-Object location, starttime


The .txt & .csv files consist of:

VIPs.txt - UPNs of targeted calendars:
user1@domain.com
user2@domain.com
user3@domain.com
```

etc...

```
Rooms.txt - List of conference rooms

Conf1
Conf2
Conf3
```

etc...

```
VIPReservations.csv - the results:

VIP       Location         StartTime
User1      Conf1            8/21/2022 13:00
User1      Conf3            7/20/2023 15:00
User2      Conf1            10/15/2023 10:00
```

Comment: If you add examples of the `csv` files, you will have a higher change to get your assistance. As an aside, [`$Null` should be at the left  hand side of the condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view#checking-for-null)

Comment: I added examples of the input/output files.... Thanks!

Comment: Here is the error I am returning: 
Cannot compare "10/17/2023 19:00:00" to "10/5/2023 12:49:19 PM" because the objects are not the same type or the object "10/17/2023 19:00:00" does not implement 
"IComparable".
At D:\Scripts\Meverlove\VIPConfRoom\Get-ConfReservationDeets_v02.ps1:47 char:43
+ ... re-Object { $_.StartTime -ge $StartDate -and $_.StartTime -lt $EndDat ...

Comment: As an aside: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-calendardiagnosticobjects doesn't mention a `.StartTime` property (though your error message suggests that it exists). It shows `-StartDate` and `-EndDate` parameters, which you may be able to use directly - they operate on the `.OriginalLastModifiedTime` property.